# I am facing an issue at build time in angular application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

when I try to build application at that time I'm getting error like this.

`Module parse failed: Unexpected token File was processed with these loader`

`.node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/wwewbpack-loader.js`

`.node/modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js`

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall node modules by following commands then build again it may helps.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. but I got my error and solution. by mistake I declare component 2 times in module.ts